# pytorch CNN get label for a single image

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm getting stuck on a function that is supposed to predict the label of a single image. I need to do this on a single image because I want to build a web app, where the user can upload an image and can get its prediction.

My CNN is the following with the base for the model :

```
class ImageClassificationBase(nn.Module):
    def training_step(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch 
        out = self(images)                  # Generate predictions
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels) # Calculate loss
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch 
        out = self(images)                    # Generate predictions
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)   # Calculate loss
        acc = accuracy(out, labels)           # Calculate accuracy
        return {'val_loss': loss.detach(), 'val_acc': acc}
    
    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   # Combine losses
        batch_accs = [x['val_acc'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()      # Combine accuracies
        return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}

    def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
        print("Epoch [{}], train_loss: {:.4f}, val_loss: {:.4f}, val_acc: {:.4f}".format(
            epoch, result['train_loss'], result['val_loss'], result['val_acc']))
```

and the model itself:

```
class BrainTumorClassification(ImageClassificationBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32,64, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
        
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(128 ,128, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
            
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256,256, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
            
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(82944,1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512,6))
    
    def forward(self, xb):
        return self.network(xb)
```

The function I'm trying to implement for testing a single image is the following:

```
from torch.autograd import Variable
transformer = transforms.Compose([
     transforms.Resize((150,150)), transforms.ToTensor()])
def classify(image_path,image_transforms, classes):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image_tensor = image_transforms(image).float()
    image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)
    input = Variable(image_tensor)
    output = model(input)
    index = output.data.numpy().argmax()
    pred = classes[index]
    return pred
```

I'm getting an error:

```
`pred=classes[index]` index out of range
```

I should mention that classes has `4` elements : `['glioma_tumor', 'meningioma_tumor', 'no_tumor', 'pituitary_tumor']`.

Answer (score 1):

A few points to note:

- Don't forget to load your trained network on your initialized `model`.
- [`Variable`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html?highlight=variable#variable-deprecated) has been deprecated, you should not use it. Gradients are tracked on tensors that have the `requires_grad` flag on. Here you are only inferring so you can actually use the [`torch.no_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html) context to avoid retaining parameter activations. This will increase inference speed.
- [`torch.Tensor.unsqueeze_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html), you don't have to reassign the result as the input itself is modified by the function. As a general note, all `torch.Tensor` functions with a `_` suffix are in-place operators.
- Most of all, you mentioned only having `4` classes, yet your last fully connected layer outputs `6` logits. In this case, you need to change this to `4`.

Here is a possible modification:

```
transformer = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((150,150)),
                                  transforms.ToTensor()])

@torch.no_grad()
def classify(image_path,image_transforms, classes):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image_tensor = image_transforms(image)
    image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)
    output = model(image_tensor)
    index = output.data.numpy().argmax()
    pred = classes[index]
    return pred
```